# The sub-window appears in the background of the main window?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a problem
When I open the main window, and then press the button that appears another sub-window(another frame), this sub-window appears under the main window(In the background), which I have to hide the main window first and then after that I find the sub-window.
I want anything I want to show, it appears above the main window, not below it

```
Frame f = new Frame();
        f.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        f.setSize(1079, 621);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);//
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
```

button that displays the drawing :

```
private void muBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        XYDataset dataset = createDatasetManchester(text.getText());

        // Create chart
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("Manchester codage", "", "", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
        ChartFrame frame = new ChartFrame("Manchester ", chart);
        frame.setSize(1080, 720);

        // TODO add your handling code here:
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }
```

Comment: For better help, please post more complete code, a [mre] program post

Comment: Don't use multiple frames. For a child window you should be using a JDialog. Specify the frame as the parent of the dialog and the dialog will be painted on top of the frame.

Comment: Original poster: Please see edits to answer and reply. Is anything in the answer confusing? Does it work?

Answer (score 1):

Without code, it is hard to guess the exact problem, but having said that, the sub-window should not be another JFrame but rather a JDialog, one created based on the original JFrame.

For a more detailed answer, please provide pertinent code.

Also read: [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636)

---

Edit:

Based on your code post: `Frame f = new Frame();`
you appear to be using the `java.awt.Frame` class and mixing it with Swing classes. This will lead to disaster since this mixes "heavy-weight" (AWT) components with "light-weight" (Swing) components and you should not be doing this.

For example of use of dialogs. Note that all code can be copied and pasted into one large class called `TwoWindowsMain.java`

Classes include

- The TwoWindowsMain class that has the main method and starts the GUI on the Swing event thread
- The FirstWindow class

  - This has a JFrame field, mainFrame, that displays the main GUI
  - It also has a JButton that displays the second window in its ActionListener
  - It has a SecondWindow field called secondWindow is displayed in the ActionListener above
- The SecondWindow class that holds the JDialog called dialogWindow

  - The constructor takes a JFrame parameter which is passed into the JDialog's constructor

```
import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TwoWindowsMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new FirstWindow().display();
        });
    }
}
```

```
class FirstWindow {
    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private SecondWindow secondWindow;

    public FirstWindow() {
        JButton button = new JButton("Show Second Window");
        button.addActionListener(event -> {
            if (secondWindow == null) {
                secondWindow = new SecondWindow(mainFrame);
            }
            secondWindow.display();
        });

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        panel.add(button);

        mainFrame = new JFrame("First Window");
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.add(panel);
        mainFrame.pack();
        mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public void display() {
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

```
class SecondWindow {
    private JDialog dialogWindow;

    public SecondWindow(JFrame frame) {
        dialogWindow = new JDialog(frame, "Second Window", ModalityType.MODELESS);
        dialogWindow.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
        dialogWindow.pack();
        dialogWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
    }

    public void display() {
        dialogWindow.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

---

Second Edit:
Regarding this code:

```
private void muBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    XYDataset dataset = createDatasetManchester(text.getText());
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("Manchester codage", "", "", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
    ChartFrame frame = new ChartFrame("Manchester ", chart);
    frame.setSize(1080, 720);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Your problem is here `ChartFrame frame = new ChartFrame("Manchester ", chart);`

You don't want a `ChartFrame` object which extends from JFrame but rather a `ChartPanel`, one that you can place into a JDialog, something like:

```
private void muBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    XYDataset dataset = createDatasetManchester(text.getText());
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("Manchester codage", "", "", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
    // ChartFrame frame = new ChartFrame("Manchester ", chart);
    ChartPanel panel = new ChartPanel(chart);
    JDialog dialog = new JDialog(frame, "Manchester", ModalityType.MODELESS)
    dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    dialog.add(panel);
    dialog.pack();
    dialog.setVisible(true);
}
```

The issue is what object to pass into the JDialog constructor for the JFrame, above called `frame`, and this will depend on how the rest of your code is created. The variable may be `this`, but I can't tell for sure

Comment: @ŚmaĦị: Please elaborate as that doesn't make sense. And again, please show more pertinent code. I can't stress this enough, again a [mre]

Comment: I had to mix between them, I am working on a project and what is required is after entering information a graphic representation is displayed, so I used JFrame to design the interface, and this interface contains button when you click on one of them displays in a new window graph

Comment: @ŚmaĦị: again please show your [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code -- I can't stress this enough. Please see the edit to my answer for an example of an MRE code showing how to use a JDialog with a JFrame

Comment: @ŚmaĦị: This is a JFreeChart issue, and you need to create a `ChartPanel` ***not*** a `ChartFrame` as per the answer edit above